# How to list class properties as it is?

Tags: python-3.x, list, class, dictionary, properties

I want to take class properties and write them to file in the order i wrote them in the class.

The problem, **dict** or vars etc' sort somehow the properties. And again i dont want it to be sorted.

For example look at this code:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = "7/11/1995"
        self.sensor_1 = -1.0
        self.sensorD = -1.0

temp = Bar()
print(temp.__dict__)
```

Till here.
The output in online python(https://www.onlinegdb.com) is:

```
{'sensor_1': -1.0, 'time': '7/11/1995', 'sensorD': -1.0}
```

I wish you understand thats its terrible!

How to solve it? I mean make a string list of properties in the order i write.

Thanks in advance.